# coverage.py how to exclude contexts

Tags: python, coverage.py, test-coverage

I run different coverage tests each with a different context.
After combining them I would like to exclude some contexts from an html report.
From my small experience and understanding of the [documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cmd.html#html-reporting-coverage-html), the context option is only used for filtering the `run` lines. I would like a way to use contexts to filter on the `statement` lines.

```
Options:
  --contexts=REGEX1,REGEX2,...
                        Only display data from lines covered in the given
                        contexts. Accepts Python regexes, which must be
                        quoted.
```

I am now looking at the Coverage.py API to find a solution